# Google Test setup help in VSCode

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code, cmake, googletest

I'm not a very experienced programmer and, when I write code on my computer, I use Visual Studio. A few weeks before, I learnt about Visual Studio Code, and I got pretty excited and I enjoyed it a lot. However, when it comes to testing code, it's giving me a headache.

In Visual Studio, I tested my code with Google Test, but I'm seeing that in VSCode it's far more complicated, and I tried everything, every tutorial I saw in order to use it. No luck and, every time, it happens more or less of the same.

For example, let's say I do the setup according the tutorial on [googletest/README.md](https://github.com/google/googletest/blob/master/googletest/README.md). I created a solution named example, containing example.cpp, example.h and test.cpp, where we find the unit tests.

example.h:

```
#pragma once

int Add(int a, int b);
```

example.cpp:

```
#include "example.h"

int Add(int a, int b) {
  return a + b;
}
```

test.cpp

```
#include <gtest/gtest.h>
#include "example.h"

TEST(ExampleTest, AddTest)
{
    EXPECT_EQ(Add(2, 2), 4);
}
```

Then, I cloned googletest to example, created and opened a paste called build, and used `$ cmake ../googletest` on the terminal. At this point, example looks like this:

```
example/
--build/
--googletest/
--example.cpp
--example.h
--test.cpp
```

When I try to run or debug the project, the terminal end with code 1 and showing the error `fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'gtest/gtest.h': No such file or directory`, which is weird, since even IntelliSense can detect gtest.

Then I tried to build with CMake, and created a CMakeLists.txt in example, and configured it to run as an executable.

CMakeLists.txt:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.0.0)
project(example VERSION 0.1.0)

include(CTest)
enable_testing()

add_executable(example test.cpp)

set(CPACK_PROJECT_NAME ${PROJECT_NAME})
set(CPACK_PROJECT_VERSION ${PROJECT_VERSION})
include(CPack)
```

But then, CMake complains saying `CMake Error: The source "C:/[...]/Projects/example/CMakeLists.txt" does not match the source "C:/[...]/Projects/example/googletest/CMakeLists.txt" used to generate cache.  Re-run cmake with a different source directory.`

I read almost everything here on Stack Overflow and in other sites, and nothing helped. What am I doing wrong?

### Edit

Also, here's the tasks.json:

```
{
  "tasks": [
    {
      "type": "shell",
      "label": "C/C++: cl.exe build active file",
      "command": "cl.exe",
      "args": [
        "/Zi",
        "/EHsc",
        "/Fe:",
        "${fileDirname}\\${fileBasenameNoExtension}.exe",
        "${file}"
      ],
      "options": {
        "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}"
      },
      "problemMatcher": [
        "$msCompile"
      ],
      "group": {
        "kind": "build",
        "isDefault": true
      }
    }
  ],
  "version": "2.0.0"
}
```

Edit
---

When I use `/IC:/[...]/Projects/example/googletest/googletest/include` and `/link C:/[...]/Projects/example/example/build/Debug/example.lib C:/[...]/Projects/example/test.obj` (I moved example.cpp and example.h to a file named example and I built a library via CMake), now I get this:

```
/debug
/out:c:\[...]\Projects\example/test.exe
C:/[...]/Projects/example/example/build/Debug/example.lib C:/[...]/Projects/example/test.obj 
test.obj 
test.obj : warning LNK4042: object specified more than once; extras ignored
LINK : warning LNK4098: defaultlib 'MSVCRTD' conflicts with use of other libs; use /NODEFAULTLIB:library
test.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "bool __cdecl testing::internal::IsTrue(bool)" (?IsTrue@internal@testing@@YA_N_N@Z) referenced in function "public: static void (__cdecl*__cdecl testing::internal::SuiteApiResolver<class testing::Test>::GetSetUpCaseOrSuite(char const *,int))(void)" (?GetSetUpCaseOrSuite@?$SuiteApiResolver@VTest@testing@@@internal@testing@@SAP6AXXZPEBDH@Z)
test.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: __cdecl testing::internal::GTestLog::GTestLog(enum testing::internal::GTestLogSeverity,char const *,int)" (??0GTestLog@internal@testing@@QEAA@W4GTestLogSeverity@12@PEBDH@Z) referenced in function "public: static void (__cdecl*__cdecl testing::internal::SuiteApiResolver<class testing::Test>::GetSetUpCaseOrSuite(char const *,int))(void)" (?GetSetUpCaseOrSuite@?$SuiteApiResolver@VTest@testing@@@internal@testing@@SAP6AXXZPEBDH@Z)
test.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: __cdecl testing::internal::GTestLog::~GTestLog(void)" (??1GTestLog@internal@testing@@QEAA@XZ) referenced in function "public: static void (__cdecl*__cdecl testing::internal::SuiteApiResolver<class testing::Test>::GetSetUpCaseOrSuite(char const *,int))(void)" (?GetSetUpCaseOrSuite@?$SuiteApiResolver@VTest@testing@@@internal@testing@@SAP6AXXZPEBDH@Z)
test.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: __cdecl testing::Message::Message(void)" (??0Message@testing@@QEAA@XZ) referenced in function "private: virtual void __cdecl ExampleTest_AddTest_Test::TestBody(void)" (?TestBody@ExampleTest_AddTest_Test@@EEAAXXZ)
test.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "class testing::AssertionResult __cdecl testing::internal::EqFailure(char const *,char const *,class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> > const &,class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> > const &,bool)" (?EqFailure@internal@testing@@YA?AVAssertionResult@2@PEBD0AEBV?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@1_N@Z) referenced in function "class testing::AssertionResult __cdecl testing::internal::CmpHelperEQFailure<int,int>(char const *,char const *,int const &,int const &)" (??$CmpHelperEQFailure@HH@internal@testing@@YA?AVAssertionResult@1@PEBD0AEBH1@Z)
test.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "void const * __cdecl testing::internal::GetTestTypeId(void)" (?GetTestTypeId@internal@testing@@YAPEBXXZ) referenced in function "void __cdecl `dynamic initializer for 'private: static class testing::TestInfo * ExampleTest_AddTest_Test::test_info_''(void)" (??__E?test_info_@ExampleTest_AddTest_Test@@0QEAVTestInfo@testing@@EA@@YAXXZ)
test.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "class testing::TestInfo * __cdecl testing::internal::MakeAndRegisterTestInfo(char const 
*,char const *,char const *,char const *,struct testing::internal::CodeLocation,void const *,void (__cdecl*)(void),void (__cdecl*)(void),class testing::internal::TestFactoryBase *)" (?MakeAndRegisterTestInfo@internal@testing@@YAPEAVTestInfo@2@PEBD000UCodeLocation@12@PEBXP6AXXZ3PEAVTestFactoryBase@12@@Z) referenced in function "void __cdecl `dynamic initializer for 'private: static class testing::TestInfo * ExampleTest_AddTest_Test::test_info_''(void)" (??__E?test_info_@ExampleTest_AddTest_Test@@0QEAVTestInfo@testing@@EA@@YAXXZ)
test.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "class testing::AssertionResult __cdecl testing::AssertionSuccess(void)" (?AssertionSuccess@testing@@YA?AVAssertionResult@1@XZ) referenced in function "class testing::AssertionResult __cdecl testing::internal::CmpHelperEQ<int,int>(char const *,char const *,int const &,int const &)" (??$CmpHelperEQ@HH@internal@testing@@YA?AVAssertionResult@1@PEBD0AEBH1@Z)
test.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: virtual __cdecl testing::Test::~Test(void)" (??1Test@testing@@UEAA@XZ) referenced in function "public: virtual __cdecl ExampleTest_AddTest_Test::~ExampleTest_AddTest_Test(void)" (??1ExampleTest_AddTest_Test@@UEAA@XZ)
test.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "protected: __cdecl testing::Test::Test(void)" (??0Test@testing@@IEAA@XZ) referenced in function "public: __cdecl ExampleTest_AddTest_Test::ExampleTest_AddTest_Test(void)" (??0ExampleTest_AddTest_Test@@QEAA@XZ)
test.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "protected: virtual void __cdecl testing::Test::SetUp(void)" (?SetUp@Test@testing@@MEAAXXZ)
test.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "protected: virtual void __cdecl testing::Test::TearDown(void)" (?TearDown@Test@testing@@MEAAXXZ)
test.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: __cdecl testing::internal::AssertHelper::AssertHelper(enum testing::TestPartResult::Type,char const *,int,char const *)" (??0AssertHelper@internal@testing@@QEAA@W4Type@TestPartResult@2@PEBDH1@Z) referenced in function "private: virtual void __cdecl ExampleTest_AddTest_Test::TestBody(void)" (?TestBody@ExampleTest_AddTest_Test@@EEAAXXZ)
test.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: __cdecl testing::internal::AssertHelper::~AssertHelper(void)" (??1AssertHelper@internal@testing@@QEAA@XZ) referenced in function "private: virtual void __cdecl ExampleTest_AddTest_Test::TestBody(void)" (?TestBody@ExampleTest_AddTest_Test@@EEAAXXZ)
test.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: void __cdecl testing::internal::AssertHelper::operator=(class testing::Message const &)const " (??4AssertHelper@internal@testing@@QEBAXAEBVMessage@2@@Z) referenced in function "private: virtual void __cdecl ExampleTest_AddTest_Test::TestBody(void)" (?TestBody@ExampleTest_AddTest_Test@@EEAAXXZ)
c:\[...]\Projects\example\test.exe : fatal error LNK1120: 15 unresolved externals
The terminal process "C:\windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe -Command cl.exe /Zi /EHsc /Fe: c:\[...]\Projects\example/test.exe c:\[...]\Projects\example\test.cpp /IC:/[...]/Projects/example/googletest/googletest/include '/link C:/[...]/Projects/example/example/build/Debug/example.lib C:/[...]/Projects/example/test.obj'" terminated with exit code: 1.
```

Comment: How much CMake knowledge do you have?

Comment: Can you also post the tasks.json that was generated from VS Code?

Comment: I don't know CMake very much, but I do know a couple of things.

Comment: You need a /I<path-to-gtest-include> in the args .

Comment: In Visual Studio, the Properties shows the Command Line output. You can review that and check what needs to be added into the tasks.json -> args attribute

Comment: Now, I got a bunch of linking problems.

Comment: Then add all the libraries you need using the /link option.

Comment: Edited the question.

Comment: I don't see the link to the gtest libraries.

Comment: Added "/link C:/[...]/Projects/example/build/lib/gmock_maind.lib C:/[...]/Projects/example/test.obj",
"/link C:/[...]/Projects/example/build/lib/gmockd.lib C:/[...]/Projects/example/test.obj",
"/link C:/[...]/Projects/example/build/lib/gtest_maind.lib C:/[...]/Projects/example/test.obj",
"/link C:/[...]/Projects/example/build/lib/gtestd.lib C:/[...]/Projects/example/test.obj", very same issues

Comment: I can only think about 2 scenarios being the problem here. Either, you still have not included all the libraries needed. Or, you probably have not specified the right run-time library, I mean /MTd or the other variants.

Comment: Apparently, it also appears four linker warnings at the beggining, pointing to the gtest libraries, like ´
LINK : warning LNK4044: unrecognized option '/link C:/[...]/Projects/example/build/lib/gtestd.lib C:/[...]/Projects/example/test.obj'; ignored´ (sorry, I didn't see)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I figured out how to solve the problem. Long things short, I used CMake to include Google Test in the project.

First, I moved example.cpp and example.h into a new folder called example and created a CMakeLists.txt to compile as a library.

example/CMakeLists.txt:

```cpp
add_library(example_lib example.cpp example.h)
```

Then, I modified the CMakeLists.txt in the root to this:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.18.2) # Set your version.
# If you don't, wou'll get a LNK1169 error and many others (don't know why)

project(example)

include(CTest)
enable_testing()

add_executable(example test.cpp)

add_subdirectory(googletest)
add_subdirectory(example)

target_link_libraries(example PUBLIC example_lib gtest gtest_main gmock gmock_main)

include(GoogleTest) # To use gtest_discover_tests

gtest_discover_tests(example) # Runs GTest with CTest
```

And now you configure, build and run! :)

Comment: I want also to thank @user3389943. He/She helped me a lot and, without him/her, I would have given up by now.